# How would you show no limit of a sequence exists

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example, how could I show that the sequence $$X=(x_n)=(-1^{n})=-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,....$$ does not converge?

I know that if it were to converge to say a limit L, we would need to show that given any $\epsilon \gt 0$ , we could pick a natural number $N$ such that $$|x_{n}-L| \lt \epsilon$$ for all $n \ge N$

But how could I show that it isnt possible?

I have written

we would need either $$|1-L| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ and $$|-1-L| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Which by triangle inequality could tell us that

$2+2L \lt \epsilon $  but I dont know how else I could proceed or go about this. Any help?

Comment: $|1-L|<1/2\Rightarrow 1/2<L<3/2$. Doing the same with the other inequality leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is to use the property that, if $(x_n)$ converges to $l$, any subsequence converges to $l$. Now the subsequence of even terms is constant, equal to $1$, hence trivially converges to $1$, while the subsequence of odd terms is constant, equel $-1$. Furthermore, in a Hausdorff space like $\mathbf R$, the limit is unique…

Answer (score 0):

Choose $\epsilon = 1/2$. Then you have

$$|1-L|<1/2,\ \ \ \ |-1-L|<1/2$$

This implies

$$2 = |1 - (-1)|= |1-L+L - (-1)| \le |1-L | + |-1 - L| \cdots$$

Comment: Yep :) Sorrry (off by 1 !)

Answer (score 0):

If this sequence converges then it converges to either $1$ or $-1$. If   it converges to $ l \neq \pm1$ then for all $ \epsilon> 0, \exists N : |x_n-l|<\epsilon ,\forall n> N$. This is absurd, $|x_n-l|=|\pm1-l| $. Now you note that if the sequence converges to $1$ then $|x_n-1|=2$ if $x_n=-1$ , thus is false the request: ... $\exists N : |x_n-l|<\epsilon ,\forall n> N$.

Comment: Oops --  "converges to either 1 or 1."

Answer (score 0):

To see this in a more elementary way, suppose the sequence converges to some limit $L$. Consider three cases:

1. $L < -1$
2. $-1 \le L \le 1$
3. $1 < L$

Neither 1. nor 3. can be, because in either case
$$\varepsilon = \frac {|L| - 1} 2$$
gives a neighborhood of $L$ that *no* term of the sequence is *ever* in – even if the sequence converges, it couldn't possibly converge to such an $L$.

So 2. would have to be true. As in the previous paragraph, choosing a small enough $\varepsilon$ shows that $-1 < L < 1$ is impossible.

So $L = -1$ or $L = 1$. In either case , $\varepsilon = 1/2$ is small enough to show that the sequence can never "eventually stay that close to L".

This is essentially @Bernard's answer shows, translated into more basic terms.